# Wrong chrome full screen resolution with multiple displays

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, display, fullscreen

I am using Google Chrome on Windows 7 64bit with two displays.  The displays have different resolutions and aspect-ratios.

My problem is best visible when playing back full-screen videos from a flash player inside chrome (but it is not flash related). The maximum size is calculated from the primary displays' ratio (or maybe horizontal size), even when the relevant window is maximised on the second screen.  The problem is also visible on websites that set the width to 100%.  The 100% then apply to the primary display, even when the window is opened on the secondary display.

Are there any known solutions to this problem?  I am observing it since many Chrome versions, do not know if it has been ever correct.

Comment: Does IE do it too?

Comment: I do not have IE currently installed to check, but I am quite sure it did not happen with IE9.  I tested with Firefox Nightly and the display is ok.  So I would say its a Chrome only issue.

Comment: I see the same problem playing back video from CBS.com in IE. This used to work way back when, but I hadn't tried it in a while. Fullscreen on the secondary monitor stays on the secondary monitor but appears to set to the primary monitor scaling (I lose video off the bottom and right side).

Comment: Both my monitors are at the same resolution, but full screen on the 2nd monitor results in approx 60% screen usage from the top-left, the rest is blank (white). This was the JWPlayer v4.4.198

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing this problem myself and I've just managed to solve it.

In my case, it was caused by the page containing the player being zoomed in. Manually forcing zoom to 100% by using Ctrl-Scroll, then clicking fullscreen worked perfectly.

Note that I've set my default zoom to 120% Ctrl-0 wouldn't work.

It appears either chrome is reporting the content size erroneously due to zoom, or flash is consuming it incorrectly.

#### Before (120%)

[image: Before]

#### After (100%)

[image: After]